# Bootstrap not working in Magento theme

Tags: magento, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a silly problem. It's probably just down to me not being able to see the wood for the trees... one of you geniuses might spot the problem immediately, or at least I hope so!

I've developed a theme for a Magento site using Bootstrap. First I built static HTML templates, which were tested for responsiveness, and they all worked fine.
I then integrated those templates into Magento... and the responsive elements stopped working. They were working initially, but at some point during the site development, they stopped working.

I've looked and looked at it and I can't see what's wrong. I presume there's some sort of conflict with Bootstrap somewhere but I just can't see it. There are no script errors that I can see and everything is loading correctly, but the responsive elements refuse to work.

Can someone take a look at the site at http://www.collaredclergywear.co.uk/ and tell me what I'm missing? I think it's probably something simple but I can't see the wood for the trees anymore.

Cheers,

Willo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing in style.css try commenting it. better remove style.css completely and test

```
.wrapper {
    min-width: 954px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something very simple I was missing... sometimes you just need another pair of eyes!